# uCrop library - it is not displaying the crop window

Tags: android

I am using uCrop as per the directions given here -https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3054#!description.

But the application is not displaying the crop window. After the below code, it goes to `onActivityResult` also `outputUri` is `null`;

```
UCrop.of(imageUri, outputUri)
                .withAspectRatio(16, 9)
                .withMaxResultSize(maxWidth, maxHeight)
                .start(RecognizeActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this sample example of their you will get the all the options, i think you have to add some other configs with setting aspect ratio

https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/yalantis/ucrop/sample/SampleActivity.java

advance config
https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/yalantis/ucrop/sample/SampleActivity.java#L257